# external javascript file injection not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-injection

I've been given this function to inject external javascript files to the rendered html:

```
function inject(src, cb, target){
  target = target || document.body;
  var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
  s.charset = 'UTF-8';

  if(typeof cb === 'function'){
    s.onload = function(){
      cb(s);
    };
    s.onreadystatechange = function () {
      (/loaded|complete/).test(s.readyState) && cb(s);
    };
  }

  s.src = src;
  target.appendChild(s);
  return s;
}
```

and this is the calling function:

```
$(function (){
  inject(swifttagurlftlpre43sc,function(script){
    var a = swifttagdiv.firstChild.attributes[2].value.substr(11);
    var is = swifttagdiv.firstChild.firstChild.src;
    var onLine = (is.substring(is.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) == 'staffonline.png');

    if (onLine) {
      $('#spanactive2').html('<span style="color: #567591;"><?php echo($content->getString('active')); ?><\/span>');
      $('#chaton2').html('<img src="/site/img/chaton.gif" alt="" />');
      $('#chat_box_timer').click(function() { eval(a); });
    } else {
      $('#live_chat_block_timer').remove();
      $('#chaton2').html('<img src="/site/img/chatoff.png" alt="" />');
    }
  });
});
```

And it's working fine on Firefox. It does not work on chrome though. Developer tools give me this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

How do I fix, or at least start to debug this?

Comment: how about logging target to the console?  console.log(target).

Comment: It does actually work for me on Chrome on this page

Comment: I tried doing console.log(target) at the very top of the function, but I don't get anything. I tried logging the target variable where the function is called and it is a valid path to the external js file. Also, the error is thrown on Firefox too, only the function that is evaluated, when the file is finished loading, works.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling this function?

Comment: @serg - added the calling function

Comment: I wanted to see what `target` is but it is still not clear - what's inside `swifttagurlftlpre43sc`? It throwing an error when trying to call `target.appendChild(s);`, so whatever inside `target` it is causing the problem.

Comment: it is a valid URL to the Kayako live chat external js file - it is actually a dynamically generated file each time it is requested. I'm just wondering why would it work in Firefox then, if it also throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess was that the DOM was generated differently across browsers, and swifttagdiv.firstChild did not have attributes[2] in chrome, but did in other browsers. What it did have was the attributes['href'] property. So the solution was to change

`var a = swifttagdiv.firstChild.attributes[2].value.substr(11);`

to

`var a = swifttagdiv.firstChild.attributes['href'].value.substr(11);`

Answer (score 0):

I've had difficulty with trying to properly access body before onload completed (I had thought that was an IE issue, but it might be more prevalent). Could that be it?